# Django, how to use 'group by' and 'max' to get complete row in queryset and display related items in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I have a model like this:

models.py

```
class Talk_comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User_info, null=True)
    talk = models.ForeignKey(Talk)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Talk(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User_info, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
```

My DB looks like this for Talk_comment:

```
id | user_id | talk_id | comment
1    10        45        first comment
2    5         45        second comment
3    5         45        third comment
4    10        45        fourth comment
```

Now I want to get rows with maximum id for a user(max 'id', group by 'user_id').

In this case I want rows with id '3' and '4'.

To get this I have following code in my view.

views.py

```
qs = Talk_comment.objects.values('user').annotate(Max('id'))
```

Now in my template I want the following:
**How to get this??** Please help

template.html

```
{% for x in qs %}
    <li>
        {{ x.comment }} in talk {{ x.talk.title }}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution for this, new querysets in views.py will be as follows:

```
id_list = Talk_comment.objects.filter(user=user_info_obj).values('user','talk').annotate(Max('id')).values('id__max')
qs = Talk_comment.objects.filter(pk__in=id_list)
```

Comment: This works because you are using `id` in annotation, and could filter using `id` as its the Primary Key. What if there was some other field(non-primary key) in annotation ? How can we retrieve the object in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

Your views.py code is problematic here. It will return only the values of the user columns with annotations, rather than returning an actual queryset which allows you to walk through the relation between Talk_comment and Talk.

I believe altering that line to the following will get you closer to your goal.

```
qs = Talk_comment.objects.annotate(max_id=Max('id')).order_by('-max_id')
```

Comment: you have removed .values('user') from the qs. Now how will the query be grouped by 'user' ?